# How to use wp_get_attachment_image or wp_get_attachment_image_src instead of $instance['single_feature_image_uri']

Tags: php, theme-development, widgets

I want to use wp_get_attachment_image() or wp_get_attachment_image_src(). But that widget is not belongs to any post type. `widget()` Image instance is `single_feature_image_uri`

```
public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
    if ( ! isset( $args['widget_id'] ) ) {
        $args['widget_id'] = $this->id;
    }

    $title = ( ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ) ? $instance['title'] : '';
    $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $title, $instance, $this->id_base );


    if ( empty( $instance['title'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    echo $args['before_widget']; ?>

        <div class="single-feature__left">
            <div class="single-feature__photo"></div>
            <div class="single-feature__left-container  content-wrapper">
                <h2 class="single-feature__title"><?php echo $title; ?></h2>
                <?php if ( ! empty( $instance['text']) ) : ?>
                    <?php echo esc_textarea( $instance['text'] ); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if ( ! empty( $instance['single_feature_cta_text'] ) ) : ?>
                    <?php $single_feature_cta_link = ( ! empty( $instance['single_feature_cta_link'] ) ) ? 'href="'. esc_url_raw( $instance['single_feature_cta_link'] ) .'"' : ''; ?>
                    <a class="single-feature__btn btn" <?php echo $single_feature_cta_link; ?>><?php esc_attr_e( $instance['single_feature_cta_text'] ); ?></a>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="single-feature__right">
            <?php if ( ! empty( $instance['single_feature_image_uri'] ) ) : ?>
                <img src="<?php echo esc_url_raw( $instance['single_feature_image_uri'] ); ?>" alt="Feature Photo 1 Right" class="single-feature__photo">
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>

    <?php echo $args['after_widget'];
}


public function form( $instance ) {
    $title                    = isset( $instance['title'] ) ? esc_attr( $instance['title'] ) : '';
    $text                     = isset( $instance['text'] ) ? esc_html( $instance['text'] ) : '';
    $single_feature_cta_link  = isset( $instance['single_feature_cta_link'] ) ? esc_url_raw( $instance['single_feature_cta_link'] ) : '';
    $single_feature_cta_text  = isset( $instance['single_feature_cta_text'] ) ? esc_html( $instance['single_feature_cta_text'] ) : '';
    $single_feature_image_uri = isset( $instance['single_feature_image_uri'] ) ? esc_url( $instance['single_feature_image_uri'] ) : '';
    ?>

    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title: ' ) ?></label>
        <input type="text" class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" value="<?php echo $title; ?>">
    </p>
    
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'text' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Your Text Field: ' ); ?></label>
        <input type="text" class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'text' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'text' ); ?>" value="<?php echo $text; ?>">
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'single_feature_cta_link' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'CTA button Link: ' ); ?></label>
        <input type="text" class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'single_feature_cta_link' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'single_feature_cta_link' ); ?>" value="<?php echo $single_feature_cta_link; ?>">
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'single_feature_cta_text' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Button text: ' ); ?></label>
        <input type="text" class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'single_feature_cta_text' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'single_feature_cta_text' ); ?>" value="<?php echo $single_feature_cta_text; ?>">
    </p>
    
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('single_feature_image_uri'); ?>"><?php _e( 'Image' ); ?></label>
        <img src="<?php echo (! empty( $instance['single_feature_image_uri'] )) ? $instance['single_feature_image_uri'] : '' ?>" alt="" class="<?php echo $this->id; ?>_img" style="margin:0;padding:0;max-width:100%;display:block;">
        <input type="text" class="widefat <?php echo $this->id; ?>_url" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'single_feature_image_uri' ); ?>" value="<?php echo $single_feature_image_uri; ?>" style="margin-top:5px;">
        <input type="button" id="<?php echo $this->id; ?>" class="button button-primary js_custom_upload_media" value="<?php _e( 'Upload Image' );?>" style="margin-top:5px;">
    </p>
    
    <?php
}
```

Now how can i use `wp_get_attachment_image()` or `wp_get_attachment_image_src()` instad of `<img src="<?php echo esc_url_raw( $instance['single_feature_image_uri'] ); ?>" alt="">`

Thanks.

Comment: You can't. Your widget only saves a URL as text, it's not saving an image ID picked from the media library. You would need to update your widget to be able to pick images from the media library and save the ID. If you want to do _that_ then you should post that question (but make sure there isn't already an answered version of that question).

Comment: Thank you @JacobPeattie, i will post this question.